# pandas warning with pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Using `pandas 0.6.2`. I want to change a dataframe to `datetime` type, here is the dataframe

```
>>> tt.head()
0    2015-02-01 00:46:28
1    2015-02-01 00:59:56
2    2015-02-01 00:16:27
3    2015-02-01 00:33:45
4    2015-02-01 13:48:29
Name: TS, dtype: object
```

And I want change each items in `tt` into `datetime` type, and get the `hour`. The code is

```
for i in tt.index:
   tt[i]=pd.to_datetime(tt[i])
```

and waring is

```
__main__:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Why the warning occurs and how can I deal with it?

If I change one item each time, it works, the code is

```
>>> tt[1]=pd.to_datetime(tt[1])
>>> tt[1].hour
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it on the entire `Series` as `to_datetime` can operate on array-like args and assign directly to the column:

```
In [72]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
date    5 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 80.0 bytes

In [73]:
df

Out[73]:
                     date
index                    
0     2015-02-01 00:46:28
1     2015-02-01 00:59:56
2     2015-02-01 00:16:27
3     2015-02-01 00:33:45
4     2015-02-01 13:48:29
```

If you changed your loop to this then it would work:

```
In [80]:
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i,'date']=pd.to_datetime(df.loc[i, 'date'])
df

Out[80]:
                      date
index                     
0      2015-02-01 00:46:28
1      2015-02-01 00:59:56
2      2015-02-01 00:16:27
3      2015-02-01 00:33:45
4      2015-02-01 13:48:29
```

the code moans because you're operating on potentially a copy of that row on the df and not a view, using the new [indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) avoids this ambiguity

**EDIT**

It looks like you're using an ancient version of pandas, the following should work:

```
tt[1].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Comment: @unutbu I think for single column it works but I agree that this should be explicit, I think earlier I had tried `iloc` and then changed to `loc`, will update

Comment: I know `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` works, but I want to get the `hour' of each item. Do it on the entire `Series` can not separate the `date` with the `time`, I tried `dt.time`, but I cannot get the `hour` separately.

Comment: You can do `df['date'].dt.hour` this is a vectorised method

Comment: the code is `
In [72]: ss=pd.to_datetime(ts)`

`In [73]: ss[1]`
`Out[73]: '2015-02-01 00:59:56'`

`In [74]: ss[1].hour`
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)`
`<ipython-input-74-d09587b5f97f> in <module>()`
`----> 1 ss[1].hour`

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hour'`

Comment: Are you misreading my comments? Also you need to post raw data and code where it goes wrong, what is `ss` here? is it a `Series`? you need `ss[1].dt.hour`

Comment: @AliceW: You are using a very old version of pandas (0.6.2). If I remember correctly, back then, `pd.to_datetime` would not raise an error if applied to a sequence of objects that could not be successfully converted to Timestamps. (Nowadays, it raises an error by default.) It would simply return the original sequence. Notice that `ss[1]` is still returning a string. That means somewhere (later) in your `ts` sequence there is an object that can not be converted into a Timestamp.

Comment: @AliceW: And it would be a very good thing if you could update your version of pandas. I'm not sure if the `dt` attribute existed on time series back in version 0.6.2....

Comment: @unutbu .dt accessor was added in [0.15.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#dt-accessor)

Comment: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) returns also settingcopywarning. any idea?

Comment: @isabella it is never a single statement that causes this, rather it's what you did prior to this. It usually happens because you filtered the df, or did `df1 = df.loc[foo]` or similar, you can google this error. or you explicitly take a copy: `df_copy = df.copy()`, it all depends on what you want to do

Comment: Thanks for the explanation EdChum. I will consider your point.